# Eclipse hotkey - shortcut modification? I mean the actual hot key command, not the key binding

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hotkeys

So lets say I want to modify the default behaviour of

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>

Which generates from

```
new Object();

Object object = new Object();
```

and selects object. Now I have to manually copy and press enter twice to go on.
I want this the be the default behaviour e.g. copy object to clipboard and move cursor to next line.
How would that be possible?

**EDIT** basically to small solution to exactly the example is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after having used to hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Can do that easily like this

[image: Keys]

Comment: Great screenshot, but it does not help to answer my question. This question is not about defining some key combiniation. This question is about modifying an exisiting hot key functionality to a not existing, new, one.